# Delay request response in browser

Tags: tools, browsers

In order to reproduce some nasty behavior I want to delay response to particular url (set of urls) in browser, ideally Firefox.

I know that in developer tools it's possible to enable throttling, but I don't want to apply it to all responses.

Is there any extension or any other method?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) from Telerik can be used to do that. Using [these examples](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/PerfTesting), you can put in a specified delay in ms per KB uploaded.